# PostgreSQL unexpected trigger behavior

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.1

### The Situation:

I have a function `fn_SetFoo()` that inserts records into table `TableFoo`.

I also have a trigger function that runs after each insert into `TableFoo`. It takes the new primary key `TableFooID` from the newly inserted row and inserts it into a second table `TableFooBar` (with a foreign key constraint).

I created a trigger that runs `AFTER INSERT ON TableFoo FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE fn_SetFooBar();`

**If I call `fn_SetFoo()` directly then everything works as expected.**

However, I have a separate function `fn_NormalizeFoo()` that processes some data and then calls `fn_SetFoo()` for each record it has processed.

**If I call `fn_NormalizeFoo()` then the only the first record is processed and the function stops.**

---

### The Question:

Why would the process stop after the first record when called from `fn_NormalizeFoo()` when the entire process runs when the contents of `fn_NormalizeFoo()` is run directly?

---

### Some Code:

```
--------------------------------------------------------
--                Insert Into TableFoo                --
--------------------------------------------------------
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION "example"."fn_SetFoo" (
    IN "Foo1" INTEGER,
    IN "Foo2" INTEGER,
    IN "Foo3" INTEGER
) RETURNS "void" AS 
$$
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO 
        "example"."TableFoo"(
            "Foo1",
            "Foo2",
            "Foo3"
        )
    VALUES
        (
            $1, 
            $2, 
            $3
        );
    RETURN;

    EXCEPTION WHEN "unique_violation" THEN
        -- DO NOTHING
END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;



--------------------------------------------------------
--              Insert Into TableFooBar               --
--------------------------------------------------------
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION "example"."fn_SetFooBar" (
    IN "FooPK" INTEGER,
    IN "BarPK" INTEGER
) RETURNS "void" AS 
$$
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO 
        "example"."TableFooBar"(
            "FooPK",
            "BarPK"
        )
    VALUES
        (
            $1, 
            $2
        );
    RETURN;

    EXCEPTION WHEN "unique_violation" THEN
        -- DO NOTHING
END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;



--------------------------------------------------------
--                  Trigger Function                  --
--------------------------------------------------------
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION "example"."tr_SetFooBar"() RETURNS TRIGGER AS
$$
BEGIN
    PERFORM
        "example"."fn_SetFooBar"(
            "TableFoo"."FooPK",
            "TableBar"."BarPK"
        )
    FROM
        "example"."TableFoo" JOIN
        "example"."TableBar" ON [SOMETHING TRUE]
    WHERE
        NEW.SOMECOLUMN = SOMETHING AND 
        [MORE STUFF IS TRUE];

    RETURN NULL;
END;
$$ 
LANGUAGE plpgsql;



--------------------------------------------------------
--                      Trigger                       --
--------------------------------------------------------
CREATE TRIGGER "SetFooBar" AFTER INSERT ON "example"."Foo" FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE "example"."tr_SetFooBar"();



--------------------------------------------------------
--                   Normalize Foo                    --
--------------------------------------------------------
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION "example"."fn_NormaliseFoo" (
    IN "Param1" VARCHAR,
    IN "Param2" VARCHAR,
    IN "Param3" VARCHAR
) RETURNS "void" AS 
$$
SELECT
    "example"."fn_SetFoo" (
        "Foo1",
        "Foo2",
        "Foo3"
    )
FROM
    [TABLES]
WHERE
    [STUFF IS TRUE]
$$
LANGUAGE SQL;
```

---

As you can see, this is a bit more complex then I originally posted. The general idea is to create a many to many relationship as each record is added.

**Just to reiterate, running `"example"."fn_NormaliseFoo"` fails after the first row; however, manually running the contents works as expected.**

Comment: You should provide some code. At least definition of `fn_NormalizeFoo()`, `fn_SetFoo()` and `fn_SetBar()` (possibly sanitized, but not too much).

Comment: I have added some code to the original post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`fn_NormalizeFoo()` is described as:

> a separate function fn_NormalizeFoo() that processes
>   some data and then calls fn_SetFoo() for each record it has processed.

However, the code shown for `fn_NormaliseFoo` is declared in the SQL language so it's not procedural, and therefore it can't do what is claimed. It can just run one query and returns its results (or nothing if no results). Such code has to be compatible with inlining into the calling query.

So the first problem is that `fn_NormaliseFoo` is declared as returning `void` but it's not compatible with the fact that it's a SELECT. Normally the function creation shouldn't even be accepted by the interpreter of the `sql` language.
Example:

```
CREATE FUNCTION f(int) returns void as 'select $1;' language sql;
```

This fails with:

> ERROR:  return type mismatch in function declared to return void
>   DETAIL:  Actual return type is integer.

A second problem would be that `fn_SetFoo` is likely to be called only once, which is what I understand from the question's *"the process stop after the first record"*. Despite the call being in the select list of a query with some joined tables that presumably produce `N` rows, there's no reason that can be seen here for the SQL engine to call it `N` times. Better for it call it only once and affect the same result to every row formed as the output of the query.

It looks a bit like you're using `sql` in spite of `plpgsql`. To make sure that a function is call N times, loop N times in procedural code and that will be guaranteed to work.

Comment: Thanks... what's most interesting about this configuration is that I have two sets of these functions that run for different sets of data. One works and this one does not. In any case, I changed from `SQL` to `PLPGSQL` and changed `SELECT` to `PERFORM` and it looks like it is running as expected.